# Remultiply matrices after SVD

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra, svd

I have a matrix A which I need to compute the SVD of, set the last singular value to 0 and then recombine(SVD cleanup) in numpy.
I did this:

```
t4 = np.random.randn(3, 3)
u, s, vh = np.linalg.svd(t4, full_matrices=False)
s[-1] = 0
t5 = u @ s @ vh
```

I am expecting the result to be a 3x3 matrix but the result seems to be a row vector of shape (3,).

Can you all please suggest what I might be doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Did you perhaps mean `(u * s) @ vh`?  s is a 1x3, so a mat mult is never going to produce a 3x3.

Comment: Yes @TimRoberts Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `s` is returned as a 1D array with the terms in the diagonal, you can construct a matrix from, using [diag](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diag.html)

```py
t5 = u @ np.diag(s) @ vh
```